# ElasticSearch in WordPress headless setup

Tags: wordpress, elasticsearch, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

We are setting up a headless frontend (Nuxt, Vue) for our WordPress site. We pull data via GraphQL.

Now we explore if / hot to make use of ElasticSearch. Any experiences / recommendations how to do the setup?

So far we have only checked the ElasticSearch plugin for WP; but as I understand it this is primarily for making ElasticSearch work within Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might be hardly opinionated, I'll try;

Generally, for Elasticsearch to work it has to index your DB Data first. Meaning, ES needs access to your Wordpress (MySQL) DB through some authentication which means you have to expose your DB somehow.

**For example;** If you are using AWS elasticsearch and you need some kind of authentication, you should let the backend talking to elasticsearch (backend using IAM roles to generate the AWS Signature). If you do it via frontend, you might have to expose your secrets which is obviously not a good strategy.

So the most common approach would be to

#### Query a backend

Through a reverse proxy. Your frontend will send requests to this endpoint, a reverse proxy will redirect to some form of backend and the backend will fetch a Elasticsearch index.

#### Query ES directly

Through the reverse proxy - although you'd have to make it secure.
Check out the relatively new [Search-UI](https://github.com/elastic/search-ui) to fetch ES directly from a Frontend.

I guess you'd rather have to figure out if you can run ES on the same machine as you Wordpress to not expose the Wordpress DB to the web.